Is the lifetime of a local lambda as a completion handler for co_spawn i.e. a function with functor&& sufficent
Question
I am getting a little confused or paranoid, given the pattern:
void setup(boost::asio::io_context &context) {
    const auto completion_handler = [](std::exception_ptr ptr) {
        if (ptr) {
            std::cout << "Rethrowing in completion handler" << std::endl;
            std::rethrow_exception(ptr);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Completed without error" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    boost::asio::co_spawn(context, coroutine_with_rethrow_completion_handler(), completion_handler);
}

Is the lifetime of completion_handler, i.e. being local, ok?

Reasoning
AFAIK of course any local capture would be bad, as they would be out of scope when eventually boost::asio::io_context will run that handler. But whats about the lifetime of that very handler i.e. functor i.e. lambda itself?
boost::asio::co_spawn takes a &&, which AFAIK should be a forwarding reference (there is a lot of macro stuff in the template list of this boost function), and is perfect forwarding that completion function into the guts of boost::asio, and the documentation of co_spawn is not stating any lifetime regards about the completion token.
So my fear is that in the end, only a reference to that lambda is stored in boost::asio::io_context i.e. context and when we actually execute the lambda in io_context::run in main after, the lambda has gone out of scope in setup, we have UB.

Complete MRE
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

boost::asio::awaitable<void> coroutine_with_rethrow_completion_handler() {
    std::cout << "Coroutine executes with rethrow completion handler\n";
    throw std::runtime_error("Test throw from coroutine!");
    co_return;
}

void setup(boost::asio::io_context &context) {
    const auto completion_handler = [](std::exception_ptr ptr) {
        if (ptr) {
            std::cout << "Rethrowing in completion handler" << std::endl;
            std::rethrow_exception(ptr);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Completed without error" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    boost::asio::co_spawn(context, coroutine_with_rethrow_completion_handler(), completion_handler);
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    setup(context);
    std::thread t([&context]() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                context.run();
                return;
            }
        } catch (std::exception &e) {
            std::cerr << "Exception in context::run(): " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    });
    t.join();
}



Why do you think it's a forwarding reference and not an rvalue reference?

A lambda with no capture ([]) is like a plain function. Thus completion_handler is not more or less than the pointer to that function. The function itself should have life-time from begin to end of process - regardless of its scope. I don't see anything which can become dangling... (Or do co-routines change these "rules"?)

@Caleth Because CompletionToken is in a template list in the definition of this overload of co_spawn, and if I understand Clion right, then that BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_AUTO_RESULT_TYPE expands to something like typename Completion Token .. Completion Token&&.

@Scheff'sCat All that typeerasure and "its like a instance of a function struct" makes me very fuzzy about the lifetime of lambdas, especially when also then passed into a template heavy forwarding library.
Of course if you could point to the paragraph in the C++ std, that states when a lambda is just like a function, i.e. has static lifetime, I would be quite thankfull :-)

I am 99% certain that it ends up as a non-reference data member of some object somewhere.

@Caleth Your 1 % and my ~ 10% of uncertainty is what is making me paranoid :-)

Sorry, I'm rather practitioner than language lawyer. I tried to google but didn't found something serious. What I found might support me: Non-capturing lambda lifecycle, https://blog.the-pans.com/cpp-coroutine-and-lambdas-lifetime/, https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines/avoid-capturing-lambda-coroutines.html

Also https://blog.the-pans.com/cpp-coroutine-and-lambdas-lifetime/

As far as I understand these, one says its still problematic, the other does not, but both are only speculating about the c++ runtime implementation. Some reason I read is, that a lambda is like a struct with the member of the capture list objects, and a type erasured function pointer. That the code in the lambda would point to a static storage duration seems clear, but what about the pointer in the struct? It would be destroyed, so dereferecing it later, would be UB.
And of course this pattern, is from a project, that is suffering from UB. So that why I have to be certain ;-(

I mean right now it seems that the type of that lambda indeed is just a function pointer to static storage i.e. a function. But what about the lifetime of that pointer itself? Its auto storage, so dead when io_context::run is called, so the big question would be, if the call tree of co_spawn has copied or referenced that pointer. First case would be ok, as the static storage is still there, but later case would try to dereference a dead pointer first, which only happens to luckily still point to the static storage i.e. UB.

The CompletionToken protocol decouples the completion mechanism. What is stored depends on the type of the completion token.
The mechanism is specialized via the asio::async_result trait: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_result.html#boost_asio.reference.async_result.requirements
One of the types provided by the trait is completion_handler_type: "The concrete completion handler type for the specific signature. ".
A priori, it is clear that a new instance of may need to be constructed. This implies that the instance lifetime is governed by the async operation, instead of the calling code.
For regular callable as the completion token, the completion_handler_type is a synonym of the user's handler argument type decayed:
using H = decltype(completion_handler);
using Protocol = boost::asio::async_result<boost::asio::decay_t<H>, void(std::exception_ptr)>;
Protocol::completion_handler_type stored{std::move(completion_handler)};

Which is implemented // HERE:
template <typename CompletionToken,
    BOOST_ASIO_COMPLETION_SIGNATURE... Signatures>
class completion_handler_async_result
{
public:
  typedef CompletionToken completion_handler_type; // HERE
  typedef void return_type;

  explicit completion_handler_async_result(completion_handler_type&)
  {
  }

The decay guarantees that any reference/const/volatile qualifications are dropped. Ergo: the handler is copied or moved.
Conclusion
As you expected the handler is not stored by reference. The reason it is taken by universal reference is to accommodate

move-only callables
generic completion tokens that might behave differently


_In fact, token adaptors can already bind references into the token/handler. bind_executor/bind_cancellation_slot store copies, but asio::redirect_error stores a reference to an error_code object. Even so, the handler itself will be copied/moved.

Out Of The Box
If you share a link to the code that exhibits UB I might take a look for potential issues.

To be honest, as this was perfect forwarding a forwarding reference, and the parameter a named variable, I guessed that it would take it by reference. But I guess the good old std::decay prevented that, like in std::bind or std::thread(). If not I have to revisit my understanding of forwarding references.
Thank you very much, now I have to decide who gets the mark, +1 both.
And the code base is commercial several thousand LOC with a NDA, but thanks :-) Best guess right now is maybe a clang version vs ibstdc++ anomalies or OS socket bug or upstream or false negative in static analysess...

It's an interesting  question, if for captureless closure there is no UB related to end of life. All because closure have to behave simlarly to reference code offered by standard document (§ 8.4.5.1 Closure types):
struct Closure {
  template<class T> auto operator()(T t) const { ... }
  template<class T> static auto lambda_call_operator_invoker(T a) {
     // forwards execution to operator()(a) and therefore has
     // the same return type deduced
     ...
  }

  template<class T> using fptr_t =
  decltype(lambda_call_operator_invoker(declval<T>())) (*)(T);
  
  template<class T> operator fptr_t<T>() const { 
     return &lambda_call_operator_invoker; 
  }
};

If we have an instance in can be cast to a function pointer, after which the object itself is not need anymore - the cast returns address of a static member function. And closure would be detected by SFINAE as something convertible to a function pointer in co_spawn, after which  only pointer would be stored. If it's how co_spawn implemented, so we have to rely on quality of implementation.

I'm confused you deem the question interesting, yet answer a highly restricted subset of it. In particular, your answer hinges on "it can be cast to a function pointer" which begs the question how relevant the answer is in practice. Your answer seems relevant only when the OP edits their code to read co_spawn(context, coroutine_with_rethrow_completion_handler(), +completion_handler); or similar?

I mean I almost asked for a cpp standard reference for the lifetime, type debate.
From what I understand both your answers complete my understand i.e. working model which is: boost::asio::co_spawn will copy in the scope of setup, at least for this specialization (exception handler). And I just realized by writing this lines, that if it would not, no matter the type of completion_handler, as long as its a named variable and not std::moved, it would be unsafe. Huh.
